# Should I ever place a function declaration in global object in javascript

Tags: javascript, global-variables

Should I **ever** place a function declaration or a var function expression in the global object? I see this happen a lot in tutorials, but when you would f.e. use function names like 'atob' or 'btoa', they would override functions of the window object.
Or should I always use function expressions and place them in const/let?

An example like this would override functions of the global object and cause problems. Blur() and alert() are built-in functions, so the alert will not work.

````
    function blur(){
    }

    var alert = function(){
      console.log("Bye")
    }

    alert("Hi");```
````

Comment: That depends, different people use different method but it is always a good practice to not overwrite inbuilt functions as in larger projects new people might face issues

Comment: Learn about [modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules).

Comment: Thanks, I will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I handle this is I always prefix my function names with "jellyBelly":

````
function jellyBellyBlur(){
}

var jellyBellyAlert = function(){
  console.log("Bye")
}

jellyBellyAlert("Hi");```
````

So, far, I've had no naming conflicts. I'm a professional.

Comment: Finally, a stackoverflow user with a sense of humor. Made my day!